# Develop a context-sensitive grammar that generates the language

Tags: programming-languages, computer-science

Can some one explain how to create a context-sensitive grammar that generates the language

`L={i^n j^n k^m l^m | n,m ≥ 1}`?

This is what i got so far:(I'm not sure that it's right)

```
S → IJ
I → iIX | iX; 
J → jJl | jYl; 
Xj → jX;
XY → Yk;
Y→ε.
```

I will appreciate if you will explain step by step, how to do it correctly or any path how to check the answer. Because I feel completely lost how to solve these problems even after reading about CFG (CSG) from the book.

Thank you.

Comment: For one, it can't be right, since the description of the language talks about `i`, `j`, `k` and `l`, while your grammar uses `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language definition `L={i^n j^n k^m l^m | n,m ≥ 1}` means a non-zero number of `i`s followed by the same number of `j`s as there are `i`s, followed by a different non-zero number of `k`s followed by the same number of `l`s as there are `k`s.

So, start with a starting rule to generate the two independent parts of teh language:

```
1. S → XY
```

Add rules for generating 1 `ij` and 1 `kl`:

```
2. iXj → ij
3. kYl → kl
```

Add rules for generating multiple 'nested' sets:

```
4. X → iXj
5. Y → kYl
```

For example, a generation chain for `iijjkkklll` is:

```
→1 XY
→4 iXjY
→4 iiXjjY
→2 iijjY
→5 iijjkYl
→5 iijjkkYll
→5 iijjkkkYlll
→3 iijjkkklll
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.
Just to be clear: So if for example i have L={i^n j^n k^m l^m p^o q^o| m,n,o>=1} than there will be 1.S->XYZ and pZq? What about if there n<=1<=m?

Comment: In the language you've specified, the `m,n,o` values are the number of repetitions of the terminal symbols.  So yes, the `S` start rule will have the `Z` non-terminal symbol to allow you to provide rules for the `p` and `q` terminal symbols.

Comment: In the second part where you say `n<=1<=m`, this means there can be 0 or 1 occurrence of the terminal symbols that are affected by `n`, but there must be 1 or more occurrences of the terminal symbols affected by `m`.  Think about the `S` starting rule for how to approach that problem.  (Remember to conform to the definition of context-sensitive grammars, which define what sets and sequence of symbols are required on both sides of the rules.)